# Grammar of "¡A comer!"

Tags: verbos

I was recently staying with a Mexican family, and during lunch, the children (ages 8 and 5) were being rather unruly.  The grandmother would command them:  *¡A comer!*

I have never heard a command in this grammatical form.  What is the use of this form of a (psuedo?) command?  How commonly is this used?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's a shorten form of "pongamonos **a comer**".

The verb is "poner" in its imperative form:

tú:

> ponte a + **infinitive**

nostros:

> pongamonos a + **infinitive**

ustedes:

> ponganse a + **infinitive**

Examples:

> ¡A trabajar!
>
> ¡Ponte a trabajar!
>
> ¡Pongamonos a trabajar!

RAE defines this use:

> [poner](http://dle.rae.es/poner):
>
> 41 . prnl. Comenzar a ejecutar una determinada acción. Ponerse A escribir, A estudiar.

So basically it means "to begin doing something".

In the shorten form depending on the context you can infer the pronoun. In your example because it was a family and most family eat together the pronoun was "nosotros" thus "pongamonos a comer".

In its imperative form it is used to command. I don't know if it is used in all Spanish speaking countries but at least in Mexico is used.

Comment: Just to confirm it's quite commonly used in Spain too, usually preceded by *¡Vamos!* or *¡Venga!*, e.g. *¡Venga! ¡A currar!* (Let's get back to work!) or *¡Vamos! ¡A cenar!* (Let's have dinner!)

Answer (score 2):

It is definitively a VERY common form.

> (Ve) ¡A dormir!
>
> (Empecemos) ¡A correr! ¡Huyamos!
>
> (?) ¡A callar!
>
> (ponte)¡A trabajar!

I feel it is oft used to interrupt an activity in favor of what you command, immediatly.